# Lipschitz Functions: Basics

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I'm working on a proof in real analysis. Here is the body of the exercise:

Let $g: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function where $g'$ is continuous and $g'(x) < 1$ on a closed interval $I$. Prove that there exists a constant $c$ such that for all $x,y \in I$, $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq c|x-y|. $$

I think I have done a similar proof before: I think it all rides on how you define your $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. I would appreciate help on constructing this solution. Thank you.

Comment: Consider the mean value theorem of derivatives applied on $(x,y)$ where $x<y$ WLOG and then use the boundedness assumption of the derivative. If I recall correctly, that’s all it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the fundamental theorem of calculus i.e. 
$$ f(x) - f (y) = \int_y^x f'(x) dx$$ and use some property of the integral.